# How can you use awk to verify HTT, and output a string as the result?

Tags: unix, command-line, awk

I'd like to find if hypterthreading is enabled on several unix machines. The command I'm using is:

```
egrep 'siblings|cpu cores' /proc/cpuinfo | head -2
>> siblings : 8 
>> cpu cores : 4
```

This (I think?) is pretty reliable - if siblings is twice the size of cores, then HTT is enabled. However, I'd like to use this in a verification script that returns either "True" or "False" - is this possible using `awk` or something similar?

**update:** After trying the answer below, with some modification:
`awk '/siblings/{val=$3;} /cpu cores/{if(val==2*$4) exit 0; else exit 1}' /proc/cpuinfo END{if($?) print "ENABLED"; else print "DISABLED"}`

I get the following error:
`/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token`('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `awk '/siblings/{val=$3;} /cpu cores/{if(val==2*$4) exit 0; else exit 1}' /proc/cpuinfo END{if($?) print "ENABLED"; else print "DISABLED"}'`

Comment: grep|egrep etc: `The  exit  status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if not found.
       If an error occurred the exit status is 2.  (Note: POSIX error handling
       code should check for '2' or greater.)
` Exit value is stored in variable `$?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '/siblings/{val=$3;} /cpu cores/{if(val==2*$4) exit 0; else exit 1}' /proc/cpuinfo
echo $?
0
```

`/siblings/` matches the `siblings` line `$3` exctracts the value 8

`/cpu cores/` mathces the `cpu cores` line `$4` exctracts the value 4

`if(val==2*$4)` checks if the value is double.

returns `0` on success

returns `1` on fail

EDIT

if you want to print those messages it easier to use the shell `if` statement

```
    awk '/siblings/{val=$3;} /cpu cores/{if(val==2*$4) exit 0; else exit 1}' /proc/cpuinfo 
    if [ $? -eq 0]
    then
    echo "ENABLED"
    else 

echo "DISABLED"
fi
```

if you still wants to do in `awk` do not use `exit` rather use the `print` within the `END` block

```
awk '/siblings/{val=$3;} /cpu cores/{if(val==2*$4) {print "ENABLED"; exit} else {print "DISABLED"; exit} }' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for, though I need a slight modification - I'm pretty new to `awk` so, apologies. I've updated my question to reflect this new (but still very related) issue.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Just curious, do shell scripts have to end in a newline? Is there any way to run a shell script in one line (i.e., I'm reading in a config file with each command limited to one line)

Comment: no. just seperate commands using `;` for example the above `if` can be written in one line as `if [ $? -eq 0 ];     then     echo "ENABLED";     else  echo "DISABLED"; fi`

Comment: Oh neato, thanks! So, I'm getting a syntax error on the single-line awk command starting at the `else` bit.. any idea why?